# android built error in android studio bubblebee

Tags: android, build

ERROR MESSAGE :
Deleting stale output file: E:\ifmsmobileapp\utillib\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_dir\debug

//Build error in android studio

How we can resolve this error ?
Deleting folder option  is not working in this case.

Comment: Please be more precise. Describe the situation. Share the detailed logs. Give as much as information as possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.